# In c++, what does an increment to a 2D array? Whats the function assert(0) doing?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, assert

I'm working on a code in C++ but i'm not sure what  `a[set][i]++;` does. I was assuming that the value located in that array was incremented by 1, but i'm not sure.
Also, what's the function of `assert(0);` in the code? 
Thank for your help!

The code block is:

```
for (i=0; i<1S; i++)
{
   if (a[637][i] < a[637][15]) 
       {
          a[637][i]++;
          if (a[637][i] == 15)
             assert(0);
       }
    }
a[637][15] = 0;
```

Edit:
Sorry i forgot to mention the background.
The definition of `a` is `uint32_t a[2048][16];`so 637 and i are values from a particular loop in order to compare them with another 2D array and then choose which line to evict. This is for a cache replacement policy but i just was curious for those cases. Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest firing whoever wrote that.

Comment: Assert is used to evaluate a equation and abort with or without a message if it fails. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9sb57dw4.aspx .

Comment: Can you show us definition of array a? assert is a c function stopping compilation if it's argument is false (i.e. 0), unless macro NDEBUG is defined.

Comment: `assert(0)` is the same as `assert(false)`, meaning that the program (in debug mode) will stop if it reaches that statement. So it means "this should never happen":

Comment: @Caribou No, it doesn't stop compilation. It aborts the program at runtime.

Comment: Note also that you can rewrite that particular statement as `assert(a[637][i] != 15);`.

Comment: `assert` is not a function but a macro.

Comment: @cdhowie You're right, static_assert throws compile time error, my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statement `a[637][i]++` increases the value of the cell `637/i` of two-dimensional array `a`.

`assert(0)` simply aborts program execution at this point (since condition `0` means `false`, defining that the assertion is never met). Confer this 
[SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34236783/2630032) for a more detailed explanation.